# Is evolutionary algorithm dead as same as symbolic AI?

Tags: evolutionary-algorithms

I am just wondering if evolutionary algorithm (e.g., genetic algorithm, ant colony optimization, swarm optimization, etc.) dead as same as symbolic AI.

Can you give me the latest situation as of June 2023?

Is rsearch still going on on evolutionary algorithm?

Comment: Symbolic AI isn't dead. Just because something else is in fashion right now doesn't mean everything else is thrown in the bin...

Answer (score 3):

Both Evolutionary/Genetic Algorithms and Symbolic AI are not dead:

- GAs are widely used for hyper-parameter optimization (see [population-based training](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.09846.pdf)), and even in [reinforcement learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.06567.pdf) (see [CMA-ES](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.00772.pdf) use in [world models](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.10122.pdf)).
- Symbolic AI is actually evolving towards combining it with deep learning. For example, [Neurosymbolic programming](https://nips.cc/virtual/2022/tutorial/55804) allows to search for programs and even embed prior knowledge. These is also a sub-field called *library learning* that uses a neural-net based-search to find subroutines, which in turn are used to yield better programs. Similarly, there is [symbolic regression](https://github.com/MilesCranmer/PySR) that aims to find a math expression representing the regression model, as an interpretable alternative to ML/DL regressors.